# Calculate the limit with integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I have to calculate the limit below:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{u(n)}^{v(n)} f(x)\mathrm{d}x.$$

I know that: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u(n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}v(n)\in \{a, \infty\}$, where $a\in \mathbb R$.

$f(\cdot)$ is well defined, integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

For the first case (i.e., the limit is in $\mathbb{R}$), the limit is $0$. Is it correct to say that $\int_{a}^{a}f=0$ without any further explanation?

What about the second case (i.e., the limit is $\infty$)?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The limits of the sequences can't equal two different things.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It is like two cases. The first case is when the sequences converge to $a$, calculate the limit. The second case, when the sequences diverge, calculate the limit. It is not equal $a$ and $\infty$ at the same time.

Comment: I think that this means that the limits can be infinity or be convergent.

Comment: @Jika Usually $\Bigl\{ $ denotes a conjunction, not a disjunction as it appears you want it to be.

Comment: @GitGud Do you know how can I modify the question accordingly?

Comment: The explanation is that the integral of a integrable $f$ look as a function is continuous. For this because you can write that the limit is $\int_a^a f$.

Comment: Since $f$ is integrable, there exists a differentiable function $F$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb N\left[\int_{u(n)}^{v(n)} f(x)\mathrm{d}x=F(v(n))-F(u(n))\right]$. Using the fact that $F$ continuous, the case where $u,v$ converge follows at once.

Comment: Maybe not. What if $u(n) = n$ and $v(n) = n^2$?

Comment: To add on Marty's comment, consider $f$ constantly $1$ to easily see it fails.

Comment: @Jika I edited the question. I hope it conveys what you want and that it is to your liking.

Comment: Is totally true thanks for the observation.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you very much. So for the first case ($a\in\mathbb{R}$), I am doing right. And for the second case ($\infty$), no one can calculate the limit without any further information on $f(\cdot)$. Thank you all.

Comment: @Jika I think that is correct. I think for the case $\infty$ we can find examples that diverge and that converge to any real number we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit of $u(n)$ and $v(n)$ is the same real number $w$, for any $\epsilon>0$ 
$$|u(n)-w|,|v(n)-w|<\epsilon$$
holds for every $n$ big enough, hence:
$$\left|\int_{u(n)}^{v(n)}f(x)dx\right| \leq |v(n)-u(n)|\cdot\sup_{x\in[u(n),v(n)]}|f(x)| \leq 2\epsilon M,$$
where $M$ is finite (given that $f$ is a Riemann-integrable function) and depends only on the behaviour of $f(x)$ near $x=w$. This clearly gives:
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{u(n)}^{v(n)}f(x)\,dx = 0.$$ 
In the second case, consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. We have:
$$\int_{n}^{2n}\frac{dx}{x}=\log(2),\qquad \int_{n}^{n^2}\frac{dx}{x}=\log(n),$$
hence nothing can be said in general.